# Splitting of text file not working properly in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, console-application

I have requirement of writing to text file.
If the file size exceeds 700MB, create new file & write to it.
I am currently writing data with `“|”` delimited from database to file & after that check the file size & splitting into multiple files, but the file `splits` in middle of the line. 
It should write till end of line or start that particular line in new file .

I need to write the column names in the first line in the newly splited file.

I am new to c#, could you please suggest me the solution with the sample code.

Please find below code to splitting the file

```
 private static void ReadWriteToFile(string fileNames)
 {
     string sourceFileName = fileNames;
     string destFileLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames);
     int index = 0;
     long maxFileSize = 700 * 1024 * 1024;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

     using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(sourceFileName))
     {
         while (source.Position < source.Length)
         {
             index++;

             string newFileName = Path.Combine(destFileLocation, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFileName));
             newFileName += index.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(sourceFileName);
             using (Stream destination = File.OpenWrite(newFileName))
             {
                 while (destination.Position < maxFileSize)
                 {
                     int bytes = source.Read(buffer, 0, (int)Math.Min(maxFileSize, buffer.Length));
                     destination.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

                     if (bytes < Math.Min(maxFileSize, buffer.Length))
                     {
                         break;
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Could you please let me know if there is any alternative best way to do this

Comment: Read & write line by line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a rewrite of a line file splitter i wrote in my beginning c# times. 
(You only have to add the column header as a string in the beginning of a new file.)

```
private static void SplitAfterMBytes(int splitAfterMBytes, string filename)
{
    // Variable for max. file size.
    var maxFileSize = splitAfterMBytes * 1048576;
    int fileCount = 0;
    long byteCount = 0;

    StreamWriter writer = null;

    try
    {
        var inputFile = new FileInfo(filename);
        var index = filename.LastIndexOf('.');
        //get only the name of the file.
        var fileStart = filename.Substring(0, index);
        // get the file extension
        var fileExtension = inputFile.Extension;

        // generate a new file name.
        var outputFile = fileStart + '_' + fileCount++ + fileExtension;
        // file format is like: QS_201101_321.txt.

        writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
        {
            for (string str; (str = reader.ReadLine()) != null;)
            {
                byteCount = byteCount + System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(str);

                if (byteCount >= maxFileSize)
                {
                    // max number of bytes reached
                    // write into the old file, without Newline,
                    // so that no extra line is written. 
                    writer.Write(str);
                    // 1. close the actual file.
                    writer.Close();
                    // 2. open a new file with number incresed by 1.
                    outputFile = fileStart + '_' + fileCount++ + fileExtension;

                    writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);
                    byteCount = 0; //reset the counter.
                }
                else
                {
                    // Write into the old file.
                    // Use a  Linefeed, because Write works without LF.
                    // like Java ;)
                    writer.Write(str);
                    writer.Write(writer.NewLine);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // do something useful, like: Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: `writer` and `reader` should be declare inside a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). This ensure that they are disposed even if an Exception is thrown.

Comment: tried your edit in visual studio and it seems to work. I did not test my solution, with the using on the writer, but it seemed weird, because of creating new writers inside the using.

Comment: That's because you can't re-assign a variable that you have declare in the `using` statement, you get a compilation error. And if you declare it outside the `using`, use it in the using declaration and re-assign it, you get a warning.  Since you need to re-assign the `writer`, you better close the current writer in the `finally` block.

Comment: And it was fun to write such a "simple" app. :D

Comment: Sure the switch of writers is a bit weird... maybe the application could be refactored to a cleaner design. I'll keep it as an exercise for my young collegues ;)

Comment: Thank you,  Markus R. & Massimiliano Kraus .It is working fine.You pleaople saved lot of my time.

Comment: @Thyagi is this answer helped you, please check it as the accepted one. This can help future developers in finding a solution more quickly.